# uitableview in uialertview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uialertview

Hi guys in my iphone app. i am using the tableview in alertview using this tutorial http://www.skylarcantu.com/blog/2009/10/10/embedding-uitables-into-uialertviews/

I'm just skipped the unwanted codes and uses only the below code

```
- (void)alertButtonPressed:(UIButton *)button { 
        UITableAlert *alert = [[UITableAlert alloc] initWithTitle:@"Table Alert" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        alert.delegate = self;
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
}
```

I used the delegate methods and included the required class files. Now i want to findout which item i have chosen. Iam getting only 0 for all the items in my tableview. Can you please help me if you have a solution or is there are other way to use the tableview in alertview? This is for chosing language option in my app. Thanks

Comment: You set the delegate but did you set the datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method from the UITableViewDelegate protocol.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Yes i add this method already. But it returns only 0 for all the items i chose.

Comment: NSIndexPath is an object, not an integer. To get the row number, use indexPath.row and to get the section, indexPath.section.